# React infinite grid with axios results in maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

i'm relative new to react and i want to create a infinite scroll gallery.

infinite grid module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@egjs/react-infinitegrid

demo code used as template: https://codesandbox.io/s/030opyqkvw

**react index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { GridLayout } from "@egjs/react-infinitegrid";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

const Item = ({ link }) => (
  <div className="item">
    <div className="thumbnail">
      <img src={link} alt="egjs" width="240" height="180" />
    </div>
  </div>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { list: [] };

  loadItems = (groupKey, num) => {
    const items = [];
    const start = this.start || 0;

    // axios.get('http://localhost:8888/api/' + start)
    // .then(function (response) {
    //   const { data } = response;
    //   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //     items.push(<Item groupKey={groupKey} link={data[i].img} key={start + i} />);
    //   }
    // })
    // .catch(function (error) {
    //   console.log(error);
    // })

    //replace this for loop with the axios request from above
    for (let i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
      items.push(
        <Item
          groupKey={groupKey}
          link={`https://naver.github.io/egjs-infinitegrid/assets/image/${
            ((1 + start + i) % 59) + 1
          }.jpg`}
          key={start + i}
        />
      );
    }

    this.start = start + num;
    return items;
  };

  onAppend = ({ groupKey, startLoading }) => {
    startLoading();
    const list = this.state.list;
    const items = this.loadItems((parseFloat(groupKey) || 0) + 1, 10);
    this.setState({ list: list.concat(items) });
  };

  onLayoutComplete = ({ isLayout, endLoading }) => {
    !isLayout && endLoading();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <GridLayout
        options={{
          isConstantSize: true,
          transitionDuration: 0.2,
        }}
        layoutOptions={{
          margin: 4,
          align: "center",
        }}
        onAppend={this.onAppend}
        onLayoutComplete={this.onLayoutComplete}
      >
        {this.state.list}
      </GridLayout>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**node app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});


const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: Number },
    img: { type: String }
});

mySchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

const myModel = mongoose.model('SampleModel', mySchema);

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));

app.get('/api/:offset', (req, res) => {
    var offset = Math.max(0, req.params.offset)
    myModel.paginate({}, { sort: { _id: 'desc' }, offset: offset, limit: 10 }).then((result) => {
        res.json({ data: result.docs })
    });
})

app.listen(8888,function(){
    console.log('starting our application');
});
```

when i replace the for loop with the axios request i get the following error:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

i have no idea how to fix this and i hope someone can help me with this.